# How can I query from a list of partition keys in Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure table where the partition key is the profile id of a user logged into the website, so if I have a list of user ids I need to fetch if there is a partition key in the table with that id. I want to return a list of ids(partition keys) that were found.

I can't seem to find any good info online, that says I can do this easily!

If needed I can just move to Sql Server instead of Azure Storage Tables

I want to do something like this

```
 var query = new TableQuery<ConnectionEntity>()
.Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey" , QueryComparisons.Equal, "1 or 3 or 4"));

 var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to **combine** multiple filters.

```
var filterOne = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey" , QueryComparisons.Equal, "1");

var filterTwo = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey" , QueryComparisons.Equal, "2");

var filterThree = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey" , QueryComparisons.Equal, "3");

var combinedFilters = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                        filterOne,
                        TableOperators.Or,
                        filterTwo),
                    TableOperators.And, filter3);

var query = new TableQuery<ConnectionEntity>()
    .Where(combinedFilters);
```

Alternatively, it might be easier to use `CreateQuery<T>()` against your `CloudTable`, which will let you write LINQ queries:

```
_cloudTable.CreateQuery<ConnectionEntity>()
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(w => w.PartitionKey == "1" 
        || w.PartitionKey == "2" 
        || w.PartitionKey == "3");
```

Comment: ok, the second looks good, but if I always have 10 partition keys. Will that really slow down the query? FYI - I will have a varying list of partition keys each time.

Comment: Are the partition keys sequential? You can use string comparison to get a range instead. Depending on how much data you have in each partition, you might need to look at a different key

Comment: No, the partition keys are my profile ids, ex. 13121, 76753, 93726

Comment: I don't think AspNet Core has this approach implemented.